# Change header image Joomla 3.6.0

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, images, header

A friend of mine asked, if I can help him in changing the header image of his Joomla Page. Since I should know how to do this in any CMS, I asked him to provide me with the credentials. However, I did not find the correct menu where I could change the header image.

I also looked up *tutorials* on the internet on how to do this, such as, [this one](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/joomla-blog/new-banner-image). According to this guide, I should go to *Extensions => Modules* in the admin menu and then look for *Images*. But I do not see *Images* in the admin menu of my friend's page. What is wrong? The used version is `Joomla! 3.6.0`.

Here is a screenshot of the *Modules* page:

[image]

Comment: A link to the site in question would be more than helpful.

Comment: http://www.kiperowil.ro/en/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "header image" you are NOT reffering to "Kiperowil" logo in header, but to trucks images in slider underneath, you can change them in 'Vinaora Nivo Slider' published in position-4.
I have seen hundreds of slide-show extensions, but this one is new to me.

Comment: I guess in the modul you can only change the selected slideshow and under components->vinaora nivo slider the images itself within the slideshow selected in the module.

Comment: Probably... I've never seen that etension before, but usually images get chosen in component, and shown via module...

Comment: @DennisHeiden: I dont have `components>vinaora nivo slider` in my admin-menu (this is how my components dropdown looks like: http://imgur.com/a/kusxH). So how can I change the slider images? Could it be that I can only change them by changing the images in the folder via FTP?

Comment: @Mikan: I need to change both, the slider images and the kiperowil logo. How can I change the kiperowil logo?

Comment: Can't help you, I'm on vacation with no access to my comp.

Comment: I see, that slider is only a module. Open the module and scroll down to "image directory" and "individual image path(s)". There you can change single images (if in the second field) or you can at least see in which directory the images are (first field), go to Joomla Media manager (content->media), navigate to the given image folder, delete images and upload new ones there.